# Dropdown SelectedItem changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

I have two dropdown , the items in the second drop down solely depends on the selected item from the first dropdown. So therefore i want the second dropdows item changes on item selection from the first dropdown. My first drop down is as follows

```
<td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropClient" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" AutoPostBack="true" Width="200px" OnTextChanged="DropClient_TextChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList> </td>
<td>
```

I wanted to use onselectedindexchanged previously , but it does not fires as required. Therefore i put my method in the onTextChanged events as below.

```
 protected void DropClient_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                bindDrEmail();

        }
```

and my bindEmail();

```
 connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT a.clientID,a.cname,c.name FROM [CLIENT] a INNER JOIN [BRANCH] b ON a.clientID=b.clientID JOIN [CONTACT] c ON b.bid=c.bid WHERE a.cname =@clientname";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientname", DropClient.SelectedItem.Text);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            drEmail.Enabled = true;
            drEmail.DataSource = reader;
            drEmail.DataTextField = "name";
            drEmail.DataValueField = "clientID";
            drEmail.DataBind();

            reader.Dispose();
            reader.Close();

            connection.Close();
```

the above works as expected, but after i select an item in the second dropdown, it does not submit the selected item as chosen . It rather submit the first item in the list by default. Also when i click the submit button, it quickly refresh and submit the first item in the list. I am confused, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show your code in Page_Load event where you bind the items to your first dropdown. And missing _IsPostBack_ check would be the reason for why _OnSelectedIndexChanged_ is not working for you.

Comment: Agreed with Prash. Sounds like you arent checking for !IsPostBack

Comment: Make sure that you have your page load codes inside if(!Page.PostBack())

Comment: !Page.PostBack() ? never heard of it . But i tried (!(IsPostBack)) and it didnt trigger a thing.

Comment: Nuru , You have to use Update Panel :)

Comment: Prash is right, you are binding your `DropClient` in page load without checking `IsPostBack` try doing the bind in a code like `if(!IsPostBack){ [your code]}`

Comment: Update Panel is not necessary in that case .. you can achieve this by using `OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboRegion_SelectedIndexChanged"` and binding the first dropdown in `if(!IsPostBack)` below is the sample code i have posted.

Comment: Ok previously the DrpClient was not in the pageload method . Now i put it there and i added (!(Page.IsPostBack)). The Result is neither the OnTextChanged nor the OnselectedIndexChanged events fires. Infact no change at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thank all for your time. I finally figured out the problem. First the reson why it does not fires the events previously was because i set the second Dropdown "AutoPostback" as true, and didn't set the same for the first DropDown which i want to fires. When i reverse this process it fires as below.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownClient" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px"  AutoPostBack="true"
                    Width="200px" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownClient_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

And

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="drContact" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" Width="200px"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

Now it fires. Second the very reason why the selecteditem from the second Dropdown changes quickly on button click and submit the first item instead, was because of the dataValueField of the second DropDown. My convine the two tables as follows.

```
 string sql = "SELECT a.clientID,a.cname,c.contactID,c.name FROM [CLIENT] a INNER JOIN [BRANCH] b ON a.clientID=b.clientID JOIN [CONTACT] c ON b.bid=c.bid WHERE a.cname =@clientname";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientname", DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Text);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            drContact.Enabled = true;
            drContact.DataSource = reader;
            drContact.DataTextField = "name";
            drContact.DataValueField = "clientID";
            drContact.DataBind();
```

Notice the drContact.DataValueField is set as "clientID" . And clientID and the  drContact.DataTextField are from different tables. The column i required is "name" and therefore have to change the  drContact.DataValueField to the primary key of the table where name is a column. And therefore.

```
 drContact.Enabled = true;
        drContact.DataSource = reader;
        drContact.DataTextField = "name";
        drContact.DataValueField = "contactID";
        drContact.DataBind();
```

The above works fine for me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `onSeletedIndexChanged` event, call same function on `onSeletedIndexChanged` event, may be it will be helpful for you

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboRegion_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

Place the code to bind the first dropdown inside the `!IsPostBack` check

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //Bind your first dropdown here
}
```

Comment: When i put in the (!Page.IsPostBack) , the OnTextChanged/OnselectedIndexChanged does not fires .

Comment: what are you actually putting inside the `(!Page.IsPostBack)` can you show me the code.

Comment: 'protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(Page.IsPostBack))
            {
                bindPhone();
                bindDropDownClient();
            }
        }'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Update Panel` .
 This is example code ,

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">Choose...</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">test1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Test2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You CAN use UpdatePanel. But it is NOT that you HAVE to use UpdatePanel.

Comment: Yah , The DropdownList is inside a panel and the panel is inside an update panel. :)

Answer (score 0):

The page load gets triggered everytime a postback happens so to prevent your code loading everytime and resetting your dropdownlists do the following:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
    //Put your code in here. This will only load the first time the page loads.
    bindDrEmail();
    }
}
```